# iOS Core Data: Confused about Core Data and database

Tags: iphone, ios, database, core-data

I am really confused on what the Core Data actually is. Or I guess my question is, when dealing with a database, would you use Core Data? Like if I wanted access values from a database would I be using Core Data to access those values? How would I approach this problem?

Thank you so much for the help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Core Data is an framework that does the work of "object persistence". In other words, it's code you can use that takes care of saving a collection of objects to disk and loading them again later. It does a lot of work to allow you to store lots of data and load only the objects you need at a time, and unload ones when memory is tight.

Core Data can use a database to accomplish this, but that's it's business, not yours. When you use Core Data, it is a black box. You tell it to save the data and then step out of the way.

If you want to interact with an existing database, such as a MySQL database on a web server, that's a completely different matter. You might use Core Data to store local copies of objects on your device, but in that case Core Data won't care that the objects are copies from some other database. It doesn't care.

Comment: Okay thanks, so my question is now, how would I interact with a database, what route would I go? And what kind of database would work best? Or if I wanted to store values onto a database server over the network how would I approach this. Thank you so much!

Comment: You seem to be asking about a web service, the back end - you would communicate with a "database server" using JSON over HTTP or similar. Maybe you should look at parse.com or other backend service to get started with whatever you want to do.

Answer (score 4):

It is a convenient, native means of storing data in your iOS applications. Don't think of it as sqlite although you can view the files it creates with various sqlite tools. Instead think of it as a tool for manipulating an object graph of information important to your app.

I've used it in two main ways. First to store a bunch of static data that is important to an app, in one case that was a large amount of location data for an indoor mapping application. What arrived as a massive CSV file of waypoints was converted to core data. Core Data was incredibly useful for this because it allowed preparing a sqlite file which was shipped with the application containing all the infomation. Updates from a web service arrive as more CSV that is added to the Core Data to keep information current. At runtime the location information object (the waypoint a user is at) is retrieved with a predicate (i.e. the point they tapped on) and that object, through its Core Data relationships, indicates where it is possible to go from that point. Core Data provided the information necessary to perform A* routing through the indoor map.

Second it is great when you have a bunch of objects arriving as JSON and you want to be able to store and access those objects later. Let's say you have a typical app where you have a User and some information about the User, let's call it Thing. Users have Things. When you want to know something about a User you retrieve the Core Data record using a predicate - typically "name" or similar - and you get all the information you stored about the User back. Again you can make use of relationships to explore the user's connections and make displaying information easy. Perhaps the User has many Things, then you can say "user.things" and you get a NSSet of NSManagedObjects representing those Things.

You use it like a database. Its utility is that it is easy to access from anywhere in your iOS code, it is easy to store and easy to retrieve information also. Faulting lets you retrieve one object and navigate to any object connected through relationships by following the relationships. Because you define the attributes and relationships yourself in the data model editor it is easily customized for what you need to store. To me it is one of the most used and most useful parts of iOS.

When you want to automate display of information from Core Data you can use a NSFetchedResultsController to initiate a fetch and to respond through delegate methods to changes to the underlying data. If you set up a UITableView to use a NSFetchedResultsController as data source, you can have the table automatically update whenever the objects displayed in the cells changed. Very useful for apps where you periodically update information and want what is displayed to be kept current.

When your object model changes it is possible to maintain all of your existing information and migrate it to the new model. Core Data manages automatic (lightweight migration) when it can, or if you have made more radical changes you can supply rules to handle the migration.

The limitation of Core Data is that it is not great for storing binaries. If you have images that you need to store, far better to store a path to the location of the image than trying to store the actual data.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, if you want a local database on your device, Core Data is the appropriate technology. It probably makes sense to start your research with the [Core Data Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/cdProgrammingGuide.html).

You can alternatively use [SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org) (which Core Data uses in the backend), but Core Data offers some material advantages and is the preferred database interface for iOS. If you decide to pursue SQLite for any reason, though, I'd suggest you contemplate using the [FMDB Objective-C SQLite wrapper](https://github.com/ccgus/fmdb).

But Core Data is generally the way to go.

Comment: +1 on the Core Data Programming Guide.  I would say that it is compulsory to read if you intend to do anything serious with Core Data.

Comment: But what do you do if you need to take advantage of a remote database?    Apple does a poor job of explaining how Core Data fits in - or doesn't in that case.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: @AlexZavatone They don't really discuss because there really is no integration between an iOS app and a server's database. You generally have a web service running on your web server that communicates with the database on the server. The iOS app's integration with the server is limited to making requests of the web service, and is completely isolated from the server's database.

Comment: Yeah, advanced techniques in this area seem to be a rather open area.  I'm surprised that techniques on this front are not more clearly explained.  I'm already doing that, but there should be an overlying "Core Data" that also includes access to external databases that can handle different needs of the device to database communication.  I think this is a glaring omission on Apple's part.  Thanks for the info.