# Can/Should Core Data be used without persistence?

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, model-view-controller, core-data

I'm building a data visualization application that will help me realize data using Apple's `Core Graphics` and `Core Animation` frameworks. I have a Python server performing the data science and communicating the data I want to visualize in JSON.

When I started making the data visuals in my `NSView` subclasses, I noticed there is a lot of data that each `Core Animation` layer maintains. For instance, if this were a candlestick graph, each "candle" would have a trade Open, High, Low, Close, Date/Time, etc. data associated.

I know that in strict MVC design Views are not supposed to handle any data management -- only the rendering of that data.

**Is this were Apple's `Core Data` framework would come in?**

All my research...

- [iOS Core Data: Confused about Core Data and database](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12809649/5569902)
- [Core Data vs. Database fundamental difference?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7375798/5569902)
- https://nshipster.com/nscoding/
- ...and many more.

...says that `Core Data` is **not a database. It's an object graph manager** that *could persist object data* if you wanted it to. It also says that ["Core Data's true function is to provide the complete model layer for the Model-View-Controller app design that the Apple API uses."](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7375798/5569902)

***So, does that mean `Core Data` can be used without its persistence feature?***

Since much of my data is *live*, I don't have much use for persistence. All of that data comes from my Python server. But, I will have a *LOT* of graphs with `Core Animation` shapes to represent them. And, the graphs will be constantly changing based on different options, server changes, and user-selected overlays.

I started to develop a separate class to handle individual `CAShapeLayer`s, the data that defined each of them, and their rendering methods. But, this isn't true MVC design -- it's an object-oriented approach, *right*?

I'm confused...

**What data should an `NSView` subclass manage, and when should `Core Data` take over?**

My research also showed `NSCoder` with `NSKeyArchiver` is an alternative, but that seems to be used primarily to serialize/deserialize or encode/decode data to a file-store or for network transfer. I'm not sure I'm looking for that.

Comment: Core Date has built-in support for in-memory storage only, https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/PersistentStoreFeatures.html so it's certainly a possible way to go.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson after reading through your link, are we suggesting that _Modeling_ data in MVC always includes a data store somewhere whether in-memory or physically on-disk? That emphasizes my last bolded question even more.